# How do you move the datepicker on PrimeNg p-calendar

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using the p-calendar found on https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/calendar. I want to change the location of the date pickers for months to be on the right side like the shown screenshot. How can this be done?

Current Calendar:

[image]

Desired calendar:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To change the visual order around globally in your app, you can simply override the CSS style in your root `style.css`.

#### style.css

```css
.p-datepicker-header .p-datepicker-title {
  order: 0
}

.p-datepicker-header . p-datepicker-prev {
  order: 1;
}

.p-datepicker-header .p-datepicker-next {
  order: 2;
}
```

[image]